# Custom authentication/authorization/OAuth2 responses - Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

So, I have created my own authorization server for my application. It also plays the role of a Resource Server, just for testing at the moment.

For consistency I would like to customize the responses for both OAuth2 endpoints (token request fails - authentication error for example), and resource server endpoints (authorization errors). I've seen various resources online which mentioned creating a custom `AuthenticationEntryPoint` or an `ExceptionTranslator` but none worked for me.

This is the `ApiError` model:

```
public class ApiError {

    private List<String> errors = new ArrayList<>();
    private LocalDateTime timestamp;
    private Cause cause;
    private HttpResponseStatus httpResponseStatus;

    //constructors, getters, setters

    private class HttpResponseStatus {

        private int value;
        private String message;

        public HttpResponseStatus(HttpStatus httpStatus) {
            this.value = httpStatus.value();
            this.message = httpStatus.getReasonPhrase();
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public String getMessage() {
            return message;
        }
    }

    private class Cause {

        private String exception;
        private String message;

        public Cause(Class<?> exception, String message) {
            this.exception = exception.getSimpleName();
            this.message = message;
        }

        public String getException() {
            return exception;
        }

        public String getMessage() {
            return message;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my `AuthenticationEntryPoint`. I've tried placing it in `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` configuration below but it did not work:

```
@Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                         AuthenticationException e) throws IOException, ServletException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        HttpStatus httpStatus = HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED;
        ApiError apiError = new ApiError(httpStatus, e, "Authentication error");
        String jsonResponse = objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(apiError);

        httpServletResponse.setStatus(httpStatus.value());
        httpServletResponse.getOutputStream().print(jsonResponse);
    }
```

Here's the type of default Spring Security responses that I would like to change:

```
{
  "error": "unauthorized",
  "error_description": "Full authentication is required to access this resource"
}
```

```
{
  "error": "invalid_token",
  "error_description": "Invalid access token: eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleAiOjE1ODY4NjkyOTYsInVzZXJfbmFtZSI6ImFkaXBvcEBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJhdXRob3JpdGllcyI6WyJST0xFX01BTkFHRVIiXSwianRpIjoiNGYxZmQ1NTItYmQxNC00NDcyLWJhOTctNjIxY2FlZmYzNGQxIiwiY2xpZW50X2lkIjoic2FmZWRyaXZlLXdlYmFwcCIsInNjb3BlIjpbInJlYWQiLCJ3cml0ZSJdfQ.IMCogr_M8Skw0R0g0pqshROh8-nms8U3zt5i1G7CXO48OcJ76V1WXTGizn5anzFFIRHk0xGhw-r46lgHhLoWB89pjCC04PAIjFwl31flKWVSW6js9QfMt4O8CL6TAXnyHShUyJxbLZnnavTL3b40iLOHNJSeIf7Ed6goqOZMwZUBDB2KKCY_rmu80Ntj69uzVBrVfXCdDW7SRy-05uTqIGlBTWf3v4NZ4lV7EYzTJOcjavkBcSJeLcNi0DpYu1enF4rLPP9MeIUdiWT9sD6FOlLjs_vXQ_rZnxj-TVVkGSYRNn4u3-Znx4WZ3QBbcDU_O_w8qrp5_JnQbXy27-fmpg"
}
```

```
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Bad credentials"
}
```

Here's how my `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` (the generic security configuration - **order 1**, the `AuthenticationManager` is configured in another `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` with **order 100**) looks like:

```
@Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .csrf().disable()
                .headers().frameOptions().disable()
                .and()
                .antMatcher("/console/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/console/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }
```

The `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter`:

```
@Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/actuator/**", "/api-docs/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/protected/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "MANAGER")
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
```

`AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter`:

```
@Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
        //enables chaining multiple types of claims containing different information
        TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
        tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(tokenConverter));

        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore)
                .accessTokenConverter(tokenConverter)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain);
    }
```

How should I set this up? I've looked over countless resources. Which `HttpSecurity` takes priority? I am a bit confused.

Comment: Just answering the question about priority, it is indicated in the OAuth2 Boot reference guide: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2-boot-resource-server-filter-order

Comment: Thank you, this is greatly appreciated. I know I've seen this somewhere since my authorization server is set up like that, but I couldn't remember where by any means.  My bad. I thought this might be the cause why I couldn't customize the responses. I'm waiting for some suggestions on that, since the setup is a little bit unusual considering the app is both an authorization and a resource server.